# What version(s) of Python are pre-installed on OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, python

In the past Python 2.6 was included with OS X 10.8.

What version or versions come with 10.9 Mavericks?

Comment: Side note: [OS X v10.9 API Diffs: Python Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/Python.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's on 2.7.5.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

My MBA, which has been incrementally upgraded from 10.7, contains the following versions of Python:

```
Python 2.5.6 (r256:Unversioned directory, Aug 25 2013, 00:03:43)
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:29)
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
```

Being that they have the same build date it would appear that all versions of Python have been updated with Mavericks.

Python 3 is not installed on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

On my rMBP, my upgrade from 10.8.x to 10.9 lists the following versions of Python in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions:

2.3, 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7.

There is no Python 3.0 listed here for me. One can use MacPorts (and probably Fink or homebrew) to get Python 3.

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds like it might depend on the upgrade path? (BTW avoid macports for Python installs. Nightmare.)

Comment: Hodgkin-huxley Did you install 2.3 yourself? That hasn't shipped from Apple since Tiger (10.4).

Comment: I did not, isn't that bizarre? Also, I wholeheartedly disagree to avoid MacPorts for python. It's sandboxed (/opt/) and plays nicely with other python things in MacPorts. In my opinion THE best way to get a custom worthwhile install of python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc.

Comment: Re MacPorts, not to extend a side debate, but if you have normal non-MacPorts Python already and want to install a library, in my experience it will spend 4 hours installing its own version of Python and create a lot of headaches. For someone starting out who hadn't used MacPorts for their Python install, I would strongly recommend `pip` or `easy_install` for matplotlib, etc.

Comment: If all easy_installs went as planned, I'd tend to agree, but IME, extending python with specific modules, etc. almost never plays nicely with Apple's python install. And that's one that seems particularly fragile, too. Better to sandbox if (and when) things go wrong.

Comment: re Macports/Apple python if your install is pure python or maybe simple C then Apple Python will be OK, If complex multiple C libraries then use Macports. ALso historically Apple python could get several versions behind + does not do python 3

Answer (score 1):

On July 2017 on Sierra 10.12.5, I have versions `2.7.10` and `2.6.9`.

The `2.6` version is also pretending to be `2.5` and `2.3`

```
$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
2.3 -> 2.6
2.5 -> 2.6
2.6
2.7
Current -> 2.7
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python --version
Python 2.6.9
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.5
BuildVersion:   16F73
```

MacBook Pro, 13-inch, 2016, non-touchbar.

Answer (score 0):

On March 2021 on Big Sur 11.2.3, I only have Python 2.7.16 which is also pretending to be 2.3, 2.5 and 2.6:

```sh
$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
2.3 -> 2.7
2.5 -> 2.7
2.6 -> 2.7
2.7
Current -> 2.7
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

The last official release of Python 2 was 2.7.18. Apple has also [said](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes) that "future versions of macOS won’t include [a Python runtime] by default".